# Facebook error code: 4 | message: Application request limit reached

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I got the error "Application request limit reached" 2 days back. So I have removed all the extra API calls from my website and added just two calls.

1. Get user details after successfully login using Facebook credential and get access token.
2. Using User access token fetch all the pages of user.

After removing extra API calls I have checked my websites after 48hours but when I tried to login using Facebook credential and trying to fetch user's pages, It throws "Application request limit reached" Error.

Can anyone please help me to solve this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: The different rate limits are explained here, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/overview/rate-limiting

Comment: @misorude Yes I have read that but as I said, on a first call after two days, when I tried to fetch user's pages after login using user access token it is throwing "Application request limit reached" error.

Comment: User rate limiting applies across different apps now, so are you using any other apps heavily (not necessarily your own) with that account? Also, do you get it for the exact API call that tries to fetch the user’s pages, not in some step before maybe? (Not sure if the error message should really say _“Application request limit reached”_, if this was about a user token.)

Comment: No there is not any other app with this account. And when trying to fetch the user's pages, I got the "Application request limit reached" error before that there is only getting user info call after successful login using Facebook credential.